# using map with a pair as a key in c++ iterator issues

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a pair and a map declared as such

```
typedef pair<string,string> Key;
typedef map< Key, double> Map;
```

i insert objects into them via a for loop as such

```
Key p (string1, string2 );
pair_map.insert(make_pair( p, double1 ) );
```

how can i find elements in the map? I am having trouble setting up the iterator with find.

Suppose I'm using `it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1,string2))`;

I've tried declaring `pair_map<Key, double>::iterator it;` or `map<Key, double>::iterator it;` but neither are working for me. How can i fix this?

the errors i get are all long invalid cast errors because of the typedef's

Comment: What are the errors you're getting ?

Comment: Sorry, why did you not try `map<Key,double>::iterator`, which is the most natural, and in fact correct (apart from using `auto`, which is the easiest)?

Comment: Also, watch out your `typedefs` you defined the map of pairs to `Map` here but it looks like you're using it as `pair_map`.

Comment: @kbok, pair_map is the variable, not the type.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I know, I was referring to `pair_map<Key, double>`, which is indeed his error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map::iterator it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1, string2));
```

And of course you can use

```
auto it = ...;
```

or

```
decltype(pair_map.begin()) it = ...;
```

in C++11.

Comment: I'd also recommend 'Key' over make_pair.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
Map::iterator it = ....
```

or, in C++11,

```
auto it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1, string2));
```

Answer (score 2):

`pair_map` is the name of a *variable*, not a *type*.

```
Map::iterator it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1,string2));
```

(as juanchopanza says) will work, as will

```
std::map<Key, double>::iterator it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1,string2));
```

or

```
auto it = pair_map.find(make_pair(string1,string2));
```

if you have C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the variable name for the iterator type, but the type name, e.g. instead of :

```
pair_map<Key, double>::iterator it;
```

Use

```
Map::iterator it;
```

Or

```
map<Key, double>::iterator it;
```

Actually, you shouldn't typedef you `map`, since it's confusing. Just use the template everywhere.

Comment: Like I said, because it's confusing. If this is a map, use map, and the reader will know what available methods he has. Else, he has to check the definition of the type.

Comment: It scales poorly to long and nested type names though IMO. I note you're not using `map<pair<string,string>,double>`, so how are you deciding which typedefs are ok and which are confusing?

Comment: Actually I think `Key` as a typedef sucks, because it has in no way *only* the semantics of a pair. It should be a class. But this is a whole other discussion.